# Google test segmentation fault with armadillo

Tags: c++, testing, c++11, googletest

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <armadillo>
// #include "collapseSwArma.h"

using namespace arma;

class simplewindowtest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        virtual void SetUp() {
        }
        virtual void TearDown() {
        }
        imat b1 = imat("0, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0; 2, 0, 0");
        imat b2 = imat("0, 1, 0; 1, 1, 0; 2, 1, 0");
        imat b3 = imat("0, 2, 0; 1, 2, 0; 2, 2, 0");
        imat cb1 = imat("0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0");
        imat cb2 = imat("0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0; 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0; 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0");
        imat cb3 = imat("0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0; 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0; 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0");
        imat res;
};

TEST_F (simplewindowtest, addtozero) {
    // collapseSwArma(b1, res, "pos");
    // res.print();
    cb1.print();
    // EXPECT_EQ(true, all(all(cb1 == res)));
}
```

It compiles ok (with --std=c++11), but segfaults every time. I can't spot anything wrong here.

Comment: I don't see anything trivially wrong either. Didn't know armadillo matrices had a constructor accepting a string. Have you tried tracking down with a debugger where exactly crashes this thing? That might give a clue.

Comment: I can't reproduce segfaults. My environment: Kubuntu 3.13.0-34-generic, gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, gtest 1.7.0, armadillo 1:4.200.0+dfsg-1. Compile options: `g++ -std=c++11 armadillotest.cpp -o armadillotest -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread`. Valgrind also hasn't found something suspicious.